# How can I trigger multiple remote shell scripts in bash to run concurrently and then wait for them to complete?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, concurrency

I have a bash script which runs a number of tasks on remote machines via SSH. Each script is quite long so I'd like to run them concurrently as background tasks. I also need for them all to complete before moving on. I know that I can use the wait command for the latter but when I stick & at the end to make it background task, it all stops working.

By stop working, I mean that the scripts don't seem to have run, but otherwise the main script still completes.

```
ssh root@machine1 'bash -s' < script1 my_parameter
ssh root@machine2 'bash -s' < script2 my_parameter
ssh root@machine3 'bash -s' < script3 my_parameter

wait

some_other_task
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me with Ubuntu 11.04:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@server1 <command.sh &
ssh user@server2 <command.sh &
ssh user@server3 <command.sh &

wait

echo end
```

Content of command.sh:

```
sleep 5
hostname
```

---

**Update:**

With commandline arguments it gets more complicated. You can use a "here-document" and `set` to set $1 $2 $3.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -T root@server1 << EOF
#!/bin/bash
set -- $my_parameter1 $my_parameter2 $my_parameter3
$(cat script1)
EOF

ssh -T root@server2 << EOF
#!/bin/bash
set -- $my_parameter1 $my_parameter2 $my_parameter3
$(cat script2)
EOF

ssh -T root@server3 << EOF
#!/bin/bash
set -- $my_parameter1 $my_parameter2 $my_parameter3
$(cat script3)
EOF

wait

echo end
```

Comment: I tried this but it failed because I pass parameters to the script. My fault for not mentioning that. I'll update my sample code. The error was 'bash: my_parameter: command not found'